# For Linear Mixed-effects Model, It seems that the ratio of var(y)/var(x) within group determine the meaning of slope for fixed effect

Tags: r, parameters, lme4

**Key Question:**
In Linear Mixed-effects Model:

- It seems that something happened on the ratio of var(y)/var(x) within group that make the slope value of fixed effect in summary table represents the anti-pattern.
- Is it reasonable to assign `group` as a random effect if the group is perfectly arranged on explanatory variable? (The range of explanatory variable within each group is not overlapped or slightly overlapped among groups.)

Recently, I simulate a data set that contain V1 and V2. Also, there is five groups which distributes on along V1 variable without overlapped or slightly overlapped. I want to run linear mixed-effects model to see the relationship of V2 and V1 with "group" as random effect.

I simulate three data set with different known relationship pairs of V1 and V2:

**1. V1 and V2 are negatively correlated within group while positively correlation among group (the slope of regression line of V1 and V2 within group is 1).**

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = 0.2 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5),
                  V2 = -0.2 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5) + rnorm(25, sd = 0.1),
                  group = rep(letters[sample(1:5)], each = 5))
lmer1 <- lmer(V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group), data = df1)
summary(lmer1)
```

[Scatter plot for simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCwBP.png)

The result is shown below. It is obvious that the slope of fixed effect "V1" stand for the within group trend instead of general pattern.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group)
   Data: df6

REML criterion at convergence: -5.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.76086 -0.59360  0.00259  0.48262  1.71834 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 group    (Intercept) 10.862546 3.29584 
 Residual              0.008659 0.09305 
Number of obs: 25, groups:  group, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.31551    1.49290  4.17387    4.23   0.0122
V1          -1.08767    0.06567 19.12717  -16.56 8.46e-13
               
(Intercept) *  
V1          ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
V1 -0.158
```

**2. Same setting as above case, while the slope of regression line of V1 and V2 within group is 5.**

```
set.seed(12345)
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = 0.02 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5),
        V2 = - 0.1 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5) + rnorm(25, sd = 0.1),
        group = rep(letters[sample(1:5)], each = 5))
plot(V2 ~ V1, data = df3, col = as.factor(df3$group))
lmer3 <- lmer(V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group), data = df3)
summary(lmer3)
```

There is the warning code `boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')` and the variance of "group" random effect become 0.
And something goes strange that the slope of the fixed effect `V2` in the summary table are the general pattern (1).

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group)
   Data: df6

REML criterion at convergence: 3.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7143 -0.7967 -0.1104  0.7870  1.4760 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 group    (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual             0.05053  0.2248  
Number of obs: 25, groups:  group, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.33870    0.10715 23.00000  -3.161  0.00437
V1           0.99300    0.03178 23.00000  31.241  < 2e-16
               
(Intercept) ** 
V1          ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
V1 -0.908
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

[Scatter plot for simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73d9T.png)

Does it mean that under this situation, what I do on lmer() function is actually just the simple linear regression?

Also, it seems that something happened on the ratio of var(V2)/var(V1) within group that make the slope of fixed value in summary table represents the anti-pattern but the boundary of var(V2)/var(V1) ratio is unclear.
Based on the fact described above, if I have a real sampled data that each groups are perfectly arranged on explanatory variable, how do I interpret the slope of fixed effect?

If you know any paper who discuss about this problem, I am glad to know that! Thank you!

I try to manipulate the ratio of var(y)/var(x) within group and run the `lmer(y ~ x + (1|group))`, the slope of the fixed effect show different interpretation in 2 cases. I want to know how to deal with the difference.

Comment: This is a fine question, but it focuses more on model interpretation than on R code. As such you *might* get a better response in [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is an interesting comment!!! Could I ask briefly about how to you cross validation to answer the meaning of slope on fixed effect? (The meaning here is to answer what kind of pattern does the slope value in the summary table get? general pattern or pattern within group?)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: You need to provide better starting values.**

The models have a random intercept by group. Graphically that means that predictions for subjects are parallel to each other and to the population effect. And that's exactly what you get with the first simulation:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes (V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = group)) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "population"), linetype = 2,
                fun = \(x) predict(lmer1, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x), re.form = ~ 0)) +
  lapply(letters[1:5], 
         \(g) stat_function(aes(color = g), fun = \(x) predict(lmer1, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x, group = g))))
```

[image: plot showing data and predictions]

Now the second simulation results in a situation where the fit is singular with the default starting values. That means you have two options:

- **accept that the random effect is zero and just use OLS regression or**
- **go into the rather arcane art of providing better starting values**

Let's depict both possible fits:

```
set.seed(12345)
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = 0.02 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5),
                  V2 = - 0.1 * rep(1:5, 5) + rep(1:5, each = 5) + rnorm(25, sd = 0.1),
                  group = rep(letters[sample(1:5)], each = 5))

lmer3 <- lmer(V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group), data = df3)
#singular fit!!!!
summary(lmer3)

ggplot(df3, aes (V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = group)) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "population"), linetype = 2,
                fun = \(x) predict(lmer3, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x), re.form = ~ 0)) +
  lapply(letters[1:5], 
         \(g) stat_function(aes(color = g), fun = \(x) predict(lmer3, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x, group = g))))
```

[image: resulting plot showing data and predictions]

```
getME(lmer3,"theta")
#group.(Intercept) 
#         114.0275
lmer3a <- lmer(V2 ~ V1 + (1 | group), data = df3, start = list(theta = 20))
#successful fit
summary(lmer3a)
ggplot(df3, aes (V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = group)) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "population"), linetype = 2,
                fun = \(x) predict(lmer3a, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x), re.form = ~ 0)) +
  lapply(letters[1:5], 
         \(g) stat_function(aes(color = g), fun = \(x) predict(lmer3a, newdata = data.frame(V1 = x, group = g))))
```

[image: resulting plot showing data and predictions]

Looking at this last plot, it is not surprising that this model is difficult to fit successfully. The variance of the random effect is rather large compared to the variance of y values.

It is your job to decide which of the two fits is more appropriate for the second dataset. I would say both could be valid and **you need domain knowledge** to decide for one.

With real data it is often easier to go Bayesian (and encode your domain knowledge as priors) than trying to find suitable starting values. Easy-to-use interfaces for Bayesian GLMMs are available as R packages.

Comment: This is quite amazing answer that refreshes my understanding on LMM. So the starting point is very influential to get the final result, which may hugely influence the interpretation. And overall, the author has to decide whether the starting point is good or not. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Btw, could I ask about the suggestion for the textbook about Bayesian LMM? It should be worth reading.

Comment: Ah, there is another question that is there any way to guess the best starting point?